# TFS 2010 Migration from one machine to another (different database versions)

Tags: migration, team-foundation-server

The company I work for have recently installed and are using TFS 2010 - we are a small company of five developers so the database are not that big. The TFS installation was initially put on an old server to see if we would actually used it so the database that this was on was SQL Express 2008 R2.

The proper development machine that this will be migrated onto has SQL Server 2008. I have tried using The backup/restore features of the [TFS 2010 Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) but this has not been able to successfully restore to another machine.

Is it possible to perform such a migration and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by upgrading the development server to SQL Server 2008 R2 - which allowed me to migrate TFS smoothly. I don't think there is a simple way (if any) to migrate to a database version that is different to the one that you originally installed. Let alone a version that is lower.